Vectorize calculating compound interest with vector of rates and contributions
I have an issue very similar to this question...
Calculating compound interest with vector of rates
...with the additional caveat that I need to add a period contribution too.
Here is an example as a loop:
# How do I vectorize this?
RateVector <- c(0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01) # forecasted rates
ContributionVector <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) # future contributions
StartingBalance <- 10000
EndingBalance <- StartingBalance

# Compound growth growth calculation loop
for(i in 1:length(RateVector)){
  rate <- RateVector[i]
  contribution <- ContributionVector[i]  
  EndingBalance <- (EndingBalance*(1+rate)) + contribution
  print(paste(i, EndingBalance))
}


[1] "1 10201"
[1] "2 10509.03"
[1] "3 10932.3912"
[1] "4 11483.01076"
[1] "5 12176.9914056"
[1] "6 12791.84097588"
[1] "7 13310.5146149152"
[1] "8 13717.8300533627"
[1] "9 14001.1866544299"
[1] "10 14151.1985209742"

It would be nice to get a vector of all values, but what I need most is the final value (in this example, 14151.1985209742)
I am trying to use various combinations of cumprod and cumsum with no results.
Note the additional caveat that I am trying to add the compounding growth BEFORE each period's contribution.
Thank you in advance.

I'm willing to be proven wrong by someone smarter than me, but I don't think this can be vectorised.

You could do some magic with Reduce like Reduce(\(val, args) val * (1 + args[1]) + args[2], Map(c, RateVector, ContributionVector), init = StartingBalance, accumulate=TRUE) but it's still a loop, just hidden under some fanciness.

sum(rev(cumprod(rev(c(RateVector, 0) + 1))) * c(StartingBalance, ContributionVector))

[1] 14151.2

Something's up with the precision here, but it's within a cent of your value. If you want the vector of all values, your current solution will be your best bet. If you tried to apply the above solution to get that vector (e.g., using sapply), it'd be at least O(N^2), whereas I believe your solution is O(N). And anyways, like @thelatemail's comment, this is also a loop under the hood.
To break it down:
rev(cumprod(rev(c(RateVector, 0) + 1))) is a vector of the amount that a contribution at the corresponding time step will grow by the end. We append 0 to the end of the rate vector since the last contribution won't grow at all. We use rev twice so that the cumulative product runs backwards. c(StartingBalance, ContributionVector), then is the contribution at the corresponding time step, treating StartingBalance as the first contribution.

The precision of the results is exactly the same. It's just not printing all the decimals. Compare sprintf("%5.10f", x) if you've saved your value to x

@thelatemail Ah, I was wondering why that was. Thanks!
